# For $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $ϵ ∈ \mathbb{R}_+$ show that $|x| < ϵ$ iff $−ϵ < x < ϵ.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have an idea where to start but am not sure how to execute the plan. I was thinking of first showing that for $a, b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $a < b$ implies $-b > -a$ so that if $|x| < ϵ$, $x < ϵ$, which means $-ϵ > -x$, and since $-ϵ < x$, $-x > -ϵ$, so $-ϵ > -x > ϵ$ and $-ϵ < x < ϵ$ when you divide it all by $-1$. But I feel like this argument is somewhat circular and doesn't use the definition of the infimum. Any help would be appreciated!

Similarly, I also have to show that for $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$, if $|x−y|<ϵ$ for every $ϵ∈\mathbb{R}_+$, then $x=y$. I think I have to refer to the above proposition to prove this but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: When you say "definition of the infimum" do you mean definition of the absolute value?

Comment: I assumed they mean the infimum because of the notation $ϵ$ they use, but now that I review the question I see they don't define $ϵ$ as the infimum explicitly. Should I just consider it an element of $\mathbb{R}_+$?

Comment: Infimum of what? FYI, the notation $\epsilon$ does not ever mean infimum. It usually means any positive real number, and often the idea is that it can be as small as you like (but still bigger than $0$).

Comment: You select epsilon to be arbitrary (maybe with some restrictions).  Once you select it ... it's fixed.  It's a real number with a real value greater than 0.  The idea is true for *every* value... it's pretty tight.  .... Which is all completely irrelevant to this problem in which the epsilon, so far as this question states, was not arbitrary, and we have no reason to assume this result is true for any other specific value smaller than epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument would be fine, except for one problem: you stated that $- \epsilon < x$ without proof. Were you assuming that $x$ is positive? You shouldn't assume that.

Like you say, a good proof must use the definition of the absolute value, so as to not be circular.
The fastest way to do it is to do cases:

**Case 1.** $x \ge 0$. Then $|x| = x$. So you have to prove $x < \epsilon$ *iff* $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$. If you adapt what you have, it is basically a proof of this case.

**Case 2.** $x < 0$. Then $|x| = -x$. So you have to prove $-x < \epsilon$ *iff* $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$. Can you show this by showing both directions? (Remember that $\epsilon > 0$.)

Comment: Isn't it $-\epsilon < -x < \epsilon$ in the second case?

Comment: @rubik No, I don't think so. The goal is to show $|x| < \epsilon$ if and only if $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$.

Comment: Oh you're right, of course!

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically have it.  There may be easier ways but this is slick.

1) either $x = -|x|$ or $x=|x|$ (or both) and $-|x| \le 0 \le |x|$  s we can say with confidence $-|x| \le x \le |x|$

2) $0 \le |x| < \epsilon $ so $-\epsilon < -|x| \le 0 \le |x| < \epsilon$.

Hence $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon $.

.... or you can do it in cases.